# Create script for deleting tables with foreign keys in order

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a script (SQL Server 2012) that deletes tables from one specific schema, I'm not using cascade delete. I'm for example getting all the tables from sys.tables for that specific schema. Is there any way of getting the tables in order that I delete first the ones with FK and after the main ones? like cascade delete but in a script. I know I can use "nocheck constraint all" but I prefer to do it directly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible sadly.

You can have a loop of FKs so that no sequence of deletes will work.

The simplest is a pair of tables where each references the other.

```
-- Pathological foreign keys
-- There is no order in which you can drop these tables
CREATE TABLE one(a INT PRIMARY KEY, b INT)
CREATE TABLE two(a INT PRIMARY KEY, b INT)
ALTER TABLE one ADD FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES two(a)
ALTER TABLE two ADD FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES one(a)
```

Comment: So basically I should use for each table the alter using "nocheck constraint all", delete the records and the put back "check constraint all". In this case the order doesn't mater right?

Comment: That is wimping out in my opinion. There is almost always an order that works - but it is too hard a problem for a computer to find it. If you have a picture of the relations you can often spot the order.